# jQuery: Replace each td within an a tag

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to replace each `td` of a `table` which has an `a` tag inside with a wrapped one:

```js
$("td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("a").length) {
    var link = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
    $("a").contents().unwrap();
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).replaceWith("<td class='link'><a href='" + link + "'> " + content + "</a></td>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some <a href="http://www.mynewlink.tld">more text</a></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some <a href="http://www.mynewotherlink.tld">more text</a></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But it only does the first one. But I want each one to be replaced.
Can anyone handle this?

Comment: please show the "before" and "after" markeup since the description is not so clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wrapInner` in order to wrap everything in the `td` with an `a`. Your `$("a").contents().unwrap();` was actually breaking your code due to it unwrapping every `a` tag rather than one. So you will have to manually target those `a` tags after you wrap everything.

See below for working example.

```js
$("td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("a").length) {
    var link = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
    $(this).wrapInner( "<a href='" + link + "'/>");
    $(this).addClass("link");
  }
});
$("td a a").contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some <a href="http://www.mynewlink.tld">more text</a></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some <a href="http://www.mynewotherlink.tld">more text</a></p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So I've to remove every `a` tags in the `link` variable. How to achieve this?

Comment: @ttcdummy see edit. Because .each is synchronous you can do it after the each function

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is

```
 $("a").contents().unwrap();
```

when it execute first time, it replacing all the anchor tag element into plain text. So next iteration it is not able to find any anchor tag. That's why it is happened only for first element. So change your code like below

```
  $(this).find("a").contents().unwrap();
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/73qqeqs3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. Wrap all the children with "*a*" tag rather than wrap it all into one tag.

```js
$("td").each(function() {
    var anchor = $(this).find("a");
    if (anchor.length) {        
       var link = anchor.attr('href');
       anchor.contents().unwrap(); // unwrap link tag
       $(this).children().wrapInner( "<a href='" + link + "'/>" );        
       $(this).addClass("link");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <div>Some text</div>
      <p>Some <a href="http://www.mynewlink.tld">more text</a></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <p>Some <a href="http://www.mynewotherlink.tld">more text</a></p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```